# Why the checked and disabled prop return false when it is disabled and checked?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, checkboxlist

Here is my script of **function A** to retrieve the properties of checkboxes and this is where it give me the wrong state:

```
var checkedCount = 0;

$('input.new-checkbox').each(function() {

     console.log('checked : ' + $(this).prop('checked')); // returned false
     console.log('disabled : ' + $(this).prop('disabled')); // returned false

     console.log('checked : ' + this.checked); // returned false
     console.log('disabled : ' + $(this).attr('disabled')); // returned undefined

     console.log('checked : ' + $(this).is(':checked')); // returned false

     console.log('disabled : ' + $(this).attr('disabled')); // returned undefined            
     console.log('checked : ' + $(this).attr('checked')); // returned undefined

     if($(this).prop('checked') == true)
     {
            checkedCount = checkedCount + 1;                    
     }

});
```

Here is the script of **function B** how I disable and check a checkbox, where **arrayA** is an array:

```
$('input.new-checkbox').each(function() {

        for(var i=0; i<arrayA.length; i++)
        {                               
            if($(this).val() == arrayA[i])
            {           
                // set the checkbox checked
                $(this).prop('checked', true);

                // disable the checkbox
                $(this).prop('disabled', true);

            }                               

        }

    });
```

I check each checkbox if its value equals to the value in array, then set the checkbox checked and disable it.

When I click/check the checkbox, it returns me the state of the prop('checked') and prop('disabled') correctly. But when it already been disabled and checked, it gives me 'false' for both 'checked' and 'disabled' properties.

Anybody know why is this happened?

Comment: Where does it give you the wrong state? Do you call the first code block after the check??

Comment: yes i call the first function after second function. so when those checkboxes not been disabled or checked by second function, the first function gives me correct state when i 'clicking'/checking' the checkbox myself (not by script). but after it been 'disabled' AND 'checked' by the script, the first function give me wrong state.

Comment: This works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/3m2cu33u/

Comment: @artm, yea it works on jsfiddle for me as well but as a whole it not fully work in my site... but somehow it not working well cross browser too... when it is in chrome, 'checked' become 'unchecked' and seems did not trigger change event of the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Using `attr` instead of `prop` try this,

```
            // set the checkbox checked
            $(this).attr('checked', true);

            // disable the checkbox
            $(this).attr('disabled', true);
```

Comment: tried but no luck.. i actually already tried all attr, is(':checked') , etc... but really no luck.. : (

Comment: i tried and yes, it does give me 'checked' = 'checked' and 'disabled' = 'disabled' in html, but the prop('checked') and prop('disabled') still false.